# Check selection in pickerView SwiftUi

Tags: swiftui, uipickerview, swift5, swiftui-list, sections

I am  a noob and I learning Swift and SwiftUI.
I want to create an application for organize the notes.
I have 2 problems.

1. I would like to control when user had selected category in picker view before pressed button. And hide button save if category is not selected.
2. Sort notes in list by category in ListView.

```css
//
//  NewNoteView.swift
//  List&Notes
//
//  Created by Yoan on 18/04/2021.
//

import SwiftUI

    struct NewNoteView: View {
        let coreDM: CoreDataManger
        
        @State var category: [Category] = [Category]()
        @State private var categorySelected = Category()
        @State private var categoryField = String()
        @State private var noteField: String = "Your note here"
        @State private var noteTitleField = String()
        @State private var showButton = false
        
        private func emptyField() {
            categoryField = ""
            noteField = ""
            noteTitleField = ""
        }
        
          var body: some View {
          
            VStack{
                Form {
                    Picker("Select your category", selection: $categorySelected) {
                            ForEach(category, id: \.self) { categorize in
                                Text(categorize.title ?? "no value")
                            }
                        }
                    TextField("titleNote", text: $noteTitleField)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                    
                        TextEditor(text: $noteField)
                            .padding(.bottom)
                      .font(.body)
                      .background(Color.white)
                      .shadow(radius: 5)
                      .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
               
                    Button(action: {
                        guard !noteTitleField.isEmpty && !noteField.isEmpty && categorySelected != nil else {
                            print("Error")
                            return
                        }
                        coreDM.saveNote(noteData: noteField, noteTitle: noteTitleField,
                                          noteDate: Date(), noteCategory: categorySelected)
                          emptyField()
                          }, label: {
                              Text("Save")
                            }
                    )
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40.0 )
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create new note")
                .onAppear(perform: {
                category = coreDM.getAllCategory()
                })
    }
}

struct NewNoteView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NewNoteView(coreDM: CoreDataManger())
        }
    }
}
```

```css
//
//  ListView.swift
//  List&Notes
//
//  Created by Yoan on 18/04/2021.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    let coreDM: CoreDataManger
    @State var notes: [Note] = [Note]()
    @State var needsRefresh: Bool = false
    @State var category: [Category] = [Category]()
    
    
    private func updateListNote() {
        notes = coreDM.getAllNotes()
        category = coreDM.getAllCategory()
    }
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
                        ForEach(notes, id: \.self) { notes in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NoteDetailView(coreDM: coreDM, note: notes, needsRefresh: $needsRefresh),
                            label: {
                                HStack{
                                    VStack{
                                        Text(notes.title ?? "no value")
                                            .font(.title2)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                            .lineLimit(1)
                                        Text(notes.dataNote ?? "No description")
                                            .font(.subheadline)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                            .lineLimit(2)
                                    }
                                    Spacer()
                                    VStack{
                                        Text(notes.date!, style: .date)
                                        Text(notes.date!, style: .time)
                                    }
                                   
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                            indexSet.forEach { index in
                                let note = notes[index]
                                coreDM.deleteNote(note: note)
                                updateListNote()
                                }
                        })
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .accentColor(needsRefresh ? .red: .blue)
        
        .navigationTitle("Your notes")
        .onAppear(perform: {
            updateListNote()
        })
    }
}

struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListView(coreDM: CoreDataManger())
    }
}
```

You can find my project in my GitHub if you need.
https://github.com/yoan8306/List-Notes.git

Sorry I'm French and my English is not very well.
I hope it's my problem it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my 1 query. Like say udbhateja
make `categorySelected` as optional
`@State private var categorySelected: Category? = nil`
For fix selection in pickerView
we need add
**.tag((categorize as Category?))**
the code is

```css
import SwiftUI

    struct NewNoteView: View {
        let coreDM: CoreDataManger
        
        @State var category: [Category] = [Category]()
        @State private var categorySelected : Category? = nil
        @State private var categoryField = String()
        @State private var noteField: String = "Your note here"
        @State private var noteTitleField = String()
        @State private var showButton = false
        @State private var presentAlert = false
        @State private var saveSuccess = false
        @State private var selection = Category()
        
        private func emptyField() {
            categoryField = ""
            noteField = ""
            noteTitleField = ""
        }
        private func checkNoteIsOk() -> Bool{
            if !noteTitleField.isEmpty && !noteField.isEmpty && categorySelected != nil {
              return true
            } else {
                presentAlert = true
                return false
            }
        }
        
          var body: some View {
          
            VStack{
                Form {
                    Picker("Select your category", selection: $categorySelected ) {
                            ForEach(category, id: \.self) { categorize in
                            Text(categorize.title ?? "no value").tag((categorize as Category?))
                            }
                        }
                    TextField("titleNote", text: $noteTitleField)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                    
                        TextEditor(text: $noteField)
                          .font(.body)
                          .background(Color.white)
                          .shadow(radius: 5)
                          .cornerRadius(8)
                            .padding(.bottom)
                    }
                if let category = categorySelected {
                    Button(action: {
                       
                        guard checkNoteIsOk() else {
                            return
                        }
                        coreDM.saveNote(noteData: noteField, noteTitle: noteTitleField,
                                        noteDate: Date(), noteCategory: categorySelected!)
                        emptyField()
                        saveSuccess = true
                          },
                            label: {
                              Text("Save")
                            }
                    )
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40.0 )
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create new note")
            .onAppear(perform: {category = coreDM.getAllCategory()})
            
            .alert(isPresented: $presentAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Error !"), message: Text("Not saved"),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))) }
            
            .alert(isPresented: $saveSuccess) {
                Alert(title: Text("Success !"), message: Text("Insert with success !"),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))) }
    }
}

struct NewNoteView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NewNoteView(coreDM: CoreDataManger())
        }
    }
}
```

But I have new problem. I think it's simple.
I would like make 2 alerts messages.
The first it's when save is success and the second is when they are problem like one field is empty or category is empty.

```
private func checkNoteIsOk() -> Bool{
        if !noteTitleField.isEmpty && !noteField.isEmpty && categorySelected != nil {
          return true
        } else {
            presentAlert = true
            return false
        }
    }
```

.

```
Button(action: {
                        guard checkNoteIsOk() else {
                        // present alert here
                            return
                        }
                        coreDM.saveNote(noteData: noteField, noteTitle: noteTitleField,
                                          noteDate: Date(), noteCategory: categorySelected!)
                        emptyField()
                        ( ..present saveSuccess alert here..)
                        saveSuccess = true
                          },
                            label: {
                              Text("Save")
                            }
                    ) //end button
                    
                  code .... 


    } //end Vstak
      .navigationTitle("Create new note")
     .alert(isPresented: $presentAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Error !"), message: Text("Not saved"),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))) }
            
    .alert(isPresented: $saveSuccess) {
        Alert(title: Text("Success !"), message: Text("Insert with success !"),
        dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))) }
```

I think it's because they are two alerts messages. And only the last message alert can display.
Thank you for your answer and your help.

Answer (score 1):

For your 1st query, change the following in your code:

Make `categorySelected` as optional

```
@State private var categorySelected: Category? = nil
```

Add if condition in VStack to show the button

```
if let category = categorySelected {
    Button(action: {
      guard !noteTitleField.isEmpty && !noteField.isEmpty else {
        print("Error")
        return
      }
      coreDM.saveNote(noteData: noteField, noteTitle: noteTitleField, noteDate: Date(), noteCategory: categorySelected)
      emptyField()
     }, label: {
         Text("Save")
       })
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40.0 )
    .background(Color.yellow)
    .shadow(radius: 10)
    .cornerRadius(10)
}
```

For your 2nd question, please clarify - do you need to show data in section based on categories or something else.

Comment: I, Thank you for your response. Button it's hidden. with your method. But I can't select category in picker. For my 2nd question I would like sort my notes by category. They category will in header of list. And row they are notes.

Comment: Got it, I will update the answer to include your 2nd point